# Executing .exe (c++) in html or converting to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, c++

Is it possible to run an EXE (c++) on a server/webpage and make the EXE return a respons, or do i have to convert this EXE (c++) to javascript?

If i have to convert the code to javascript, how would i do that? I know the basics of javascript, but i don't know how to read and write to .txt files.

Basically my code is a login system that i want to use for my website, so i don't have to use mysql or a database. I know this is a slow and probably a dumb way of doing it, but it's for a project. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:    You press the login button, then i you're prompted with the EXE file as you can see above. Then the EXE file sends back to the server, if the login was successful and the info. The EXE file has to be on the server, so the client doesn't have to download it.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
void cls() { system("cls"); }

bool mainPage(string &username, string &password) {
    cls();
    cout << "Username: "; getline(cin, username);
    cout << "Password: "; getline(cin, password);
    if(username != "" && password != "") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool checkLogin(string &username, string &password, string &email, string &firstName, string &lastName) {
    string pw = "";

    ifstream ifile(username + ".txt");
    if(ifile.is_open()) {
        ifile >> pw >> email >> firstName >> lastName;
        if(pw == password) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool loginFail() {
    string fail = "";
    string undef = "";

    cls();
    cout << "'reg'" << endl;
    cout << "'main'" << endl;
    getline(cin, fail);
    if(fail == "reg") {
        return true;
    }
    else if(fail == "main") {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nCould not understand you." << endl;
        getline(cin, undef);
        return loginFail();
    }
}

bool regist() {
    string un;
    string pw;
    string em;
    string fn;
    string ln;
    string undef = "";

    cls();
    cout << "'main'" << endl;
    cout << "\nNew username: "; getline(cin, un);
    cout << "New password: "; getline(cin, pw);
    if((un != "" && pw != "") && (un != "main" && pw != "main")) {
        ifstream ifile(un + ".txt");
        if (ifile.is_open()) {
            cout << "\nThis username is already taken." << endl;
            getline(cin, undef);
            return regist();
        }
        else {
            cout << "\nEmail: "; getline(cin, em);
            cout << "\nFirst name: "; getline(cin, fn);
            cout << "Last name: "; getline(cin, ln);
            if(em != "" && fn != "" && ln != "") {
                ofstream ofile;
                ofile.open(un + ".txt");
                if (ofile.is_open()) {
                    ofile << pw << endl;
                    ofile << em << endl;
                    ofile << fn << endl;
                    ofile << ln << endl;
                    ofile.close();
                    cout << "\nFile was successfully written to." << endl;
                    getline(cin, undef);
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "\nFile could not open." << endl;
                    getline(cin, undef);
                    return regist();
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "\nYou didn't enter one of the above." << endl;
                getline(cin, undef);
                return regist();
            }
        }
    }
    else if(un == "main" || pw == "main") {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nYou didn't do it correct." << endl;
        getline(cin, undef);
        return regist();
    }
}

void loginSuccess(string username, string password, string email, string firstName, string lastName) {
    string undef = "";

    cls();
    cout << "You have successfully logged in." << endl;
    cout << "\nUsername: " << username << endl;
    cout << "Password: " << password << endl;
    cout << "\nEmail: " << email << endl;
    cout << "\nFrist name: " << firstName << endl;
    cout << "Last name: " << lastName << endl;
    getline(cin, undef);
}

int main(void) {
    system("color a");
    string username = "";
    string password = "";
    string email = "";
    string firstName = "";
    string lastName = "";

    if(!mainPage(username, password)) {
        return main();
    }
    else {
        if(!checkLogin(username, password, email, firstName, lastName)) {
            if(!loginFail()) {
                return main();
            }
            else {
                if (!regist()) {
                    return main();
                }
                else {
                    return main();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            loginSuccess(username, password, email, firstName, lastName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Google "CGI C++" Starter page: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm

Comment: But i want it like this. You press the login button, then i you're prompted with the EXE file as you can see above. Then the EXE file sends back to the server, if the login was successful and the info. The EXE file has to be on the server, so the client doesn't have to download it.

Comment: CGI programs run server side. A C++ program can be a CGI program.  See the 1st example on the page I linked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write in File System from Javascript in a browser. I think that you should do your application using client-server architecture. For example, the client will be a simple HTML page with inputs for username and passwords, the server will save and check user's credentials. In this case, you can use Javascript for sending data from your page to the server.

Comment: But this will require a mysql database, because i want the server to remember the accounts once they have been registered. So even if i close the server, it still has the accounts that are created.